# Login name not appearing in an android app

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have made a login app in android .I want to display the name of the user in everytab of my app.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.home); 
    final TextView txtuser=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtUser);
    txtuser.setText("Welcome "+getIntent().getStringExtra(DataBase_Server.NAME));
}
```

Whenever the user login his name does appear but when he clicks on some different tab and then redirects to the home tab the name of the user disappears

Answer (score 0):

If the name no longer appears, it means that the intent returned by `getIntent()` has changed and no longer contains the name extra.

It would be better if you store the name after fetching it from the intent. How you store it depends on how long you want it to persist. You could use a preference or a database to store it, and then remove the value when the user is logged out.